# How to enable asp.net in iis8

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-8

I can't view asp.net pages on iis 8...
I have gone into application pools and changed managed pipeline mode to classic instead of integrated for asp.net v4.0.
I have also reinstalled asp.net v4 with aspnet_regiis.exe -ir
Any ideas what else i could try?

Comment: Seems like this nice question should be on ServerFault

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Is not a simple task to install and use asp.net with IIS8 and the best way is to look at the IIS site about that on this step by step instructions.

http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-using-aspnet-35-and-aspnet-45

Comment: Not sure how I never found this link... Thanks :)